# Create an array in bash from given start and end point

Tags: arrays, bash

I have this code that works:

```
$ array=( {100..300..100} )
$ for k in ${array[@]} ; do echo $k ; done
100
200
300
```

I want to parametrize the start and end points (and also the increment, because why not?)
I tried this:

```
$ low=100
$ high=300
$ incr=100
$ array=( {$low..$high..$incr} )
```

But it didn't work:

```
$ for k in ${array[@]} ; do echo $k ; done
{100..300..100}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From bash manual:

> A sequence expression takes the form `{x..y[..incr]}`, where x and y are **either integers or single characters**, and incr, an optional increment, is **an integer**.

So, parameter and variable expansion are not performed on `x`, `y` and `incr`. You should use `seq`:

```
arr=( $(seq $low $incr $high) )
```